# View getting cut off when using React Navigation Header

Tags: android, react-native

My view is getting cut off on android with React Navigation's header (it works fine on IOS). I have tried changing the windowSoftInputMode to adjustPan to no avail. No matter what content I put in the View it gets cut off. Heres a minimal version of the code:

```
page.jsx
<View style={styles.container}>
...
</View>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Colors.White.rgb,
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    },
});
```

```
<Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen
          name="screen"
          component={screenPrimary}
          options={({ navigation, route }) => ({
              headerLeft: () => <BackButton goBack={navigation.goBack} />,
              headerTitle: 'Details',
              title: 'Details',
              headerTitleAlign: "center",
           })}
    />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

[image: This is a sample of what it looks like]